# AnyLogic: "root.rackPick.attach" The agent is not in the network

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Truck is not going to its destination point and is showing this error.
`root.rackPick.attach`
The agent is not in the network.

**An image of the error:**
[image]

RackPick the exit block image

[image]

I'm looking forward to your positive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the On Exit of the unbatch block type

```
agent.jumpTo(....);
```

Replace the dots with the location where your agents are supposed to be (e.g. node). That location should be part of the network that includes the racks.